# IIS7 - How to password protect a single folder using a Web.config file?

Tags: security, iis, iis-7, web-config, password-protection

I have a folder that contains log files.  They're not super critical, but I don't want total strangers looking through them.  I'd like to put a password on that one folder.  The folder and its contents are served straight up from IIS, so I'm not looking for a coding solution.

With Apache I'd use a `.htaccess` file.

With IIS it's possible to use multiple `Web.config` files at various levels to control this kind of thing.

So, what goes in the `Web.config` file that allows me to require a password when accessing this folder?

- I'm happy for the password to pop up in a dialog like old-school websites used to do (not sure what this is called -- I think it is digest authentication) and so avoid any `loginUrl` redirection stuff
- I'm happy to put the password in the `Web.config` file in plain text if it's easier

The application is internet facing and running on shared hosting, so I don't have much control over the box beyond what I can configure in `Web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the `<location path="..."/>` element of web.config file.

Check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871) link for step-by-step instructions..

Comment: That link just shows forms-based authentication, where you have to create code to allow for passwords.  I think what I want is digest authentication.  Do you have any information on that?

Comment: You can easily use Windows Authentication and let AD handle the validations.. you would just use <authentication mode="Windows" /> instead

Comment: This is an internet app running on shared hosting.  I do not have much control over the box at all.

Comment: In that case Forms auth is the best option for you... If you have access to create windows logins then go with Windows auth

Comment: Doesn't forms authentication require me to provide a login form with some code behind, etc?  With Apache I believe you can just say _ask for uname/pwd for this folder, and accept admin/foobar_.  Any links would be appreciated.

Comment: In fact, I'm already using forms authentication for users of my site.  All I want to do is put a password on a particular folder and not require visitors to be a user of the site, but they should have the password.

Comment: @Drew: I don't have any other pointers to exactly replicate what can be done via htaccess. However I still don;t see what's the issue with using the forms auth for this folder too if you are already using it.

Comment: @Drew: the simple answer is that unfortunately this can not be done as easy via web.config as with htaccess.